# Remove ionic android platform manually?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I Accidentally deleted the "platforms" folder and I tried to run the command

> ionic cordova platform rm android

but it shows the error

`EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'ionicapp\platforms\android\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dexBuilder\debug\5.jar'`
 and when I run the command

> ionic cordova platform add android

but it says

`Platform android already added.`

I have tried reinstalling cordova but didn't change anything.

please Help.

Comment: Which os you are using? if its linux or mac use sudo command to remove `sudo ionic cordova platform  rm android`

Comment: Please check config.xml file and find <platform name="android"> section is available or not. If it available then manually remove whole <platform name="android"> section from the config.xml file and then reinstall platform by running ionic cordova platform add android. And make sure to run cli as administrator.

Comment: @RahulCv i'm using Windows

Comment: Check whether Any ide is opened these files. Then close the ide. Commandline run as administrator and remove the platform.

Comment: tried closing the ide  nothing changed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might Sound funny I simply Restarted My PC. and everything Works Fine

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete `platforms\android` manually then try again :)